# Problem with MeshOrderAlteration to create a 2nd order ElementMesh

Tags: mesh, finite-element-method

After working on [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/78806/ndsolve-and-fem-support-for-non-conformal-meshes-of-a-disk-with-kernel-crash) 2D domain, I'm trying to reproduce the same ideas to create a mesh of a sphere composed of `QuadElement`, instead of more simple and common `TetrahedronElement`. One of the reason for this choice is to reduce the computational effort, exploit simmetries, and possibly getting a higher quality mesh.

The key idea/requirement is still to increase the tangential density of `QuadElement` while moving away from the center.

In the referred question user21 recommended to use TriangleElement to join layers with different densities of `QuadElement`, but unfortunately in 3D we cannot use `TetrahedronElement` to join layers of `HexahedronElement` (peraphs, the use of `TetrahedronElement` will vanish the effort to reduce the computational cost).

So researching a bit, and implementing a lot, I managed to create a mesh of this type:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The code I built to do this is very long and complex (for me at least), so I don't think it is useful to post here.

I encounter a problem when I try to convert my first-order mesh to second order using `MeshOrderAlteration` (see reffered question where user21 write about this undocumented function).

Also in this simpler case the function apparently do nothing.

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
mesh = Import["http://1drv.ms/1Nu6qCC", "ExpressionML"];
NDSolve`FEM`ElementMeshQ[mesh]
MeshRegion@mesh
mesh = MeshOrderAlteration[mesh, 2];
mesh["MeshOrder"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

> True
>
> 1

I'm not sure if I made some mistake while creating the first-order mesh but I didn't get any error message.

## UPDATE

Thanks to **MichealE2** who discovered this behavior is related to the fact the mesh is created with several `HexahedronElement` for convenience (each one represents a "shell").

*Please note that in 2D `MeshOrderAlteration` apparently works with many elements and also different types of elements.*

Editing one sample in the tutorial [Element Mesh Generation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/ElementMeshCreation.html) prove this behavior is not only related to my specific mesh.

```
coordinates = 
  N[Join[{{0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}}, 
    Table[{Sin[i], Cos[i], 0}, {i, 0, 2 \[Pi] - \[Pi]/4, \[Pi]/4}]]];
mesh = ToElementMesh["Coordinates" -> coordinates, "MeshElements" ->
    TetrahedronElement@*
      List /@ {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 4, 5}, {1, 2, 5, 6}, {1, 2, 6, 
       7}, {1, 2, 7, 8}, {1, 2, 8, 9}, {1, 2, 9, 10}, {1, 2, 10, 3}}
   ];
mesh = MeshOrderAlteration[mesh, 2];
mesh["MeshOrder"]
```

> 1

```
mesh = ToElementMesh["Coordinates" -> coordinates, "MeshElements" -> {
     TetrahedronElement[{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 4, 5}, {1, 2, 5, 6}, {1,
         2, 6, 7}, {1, 2, 7, 8}, {1, 2, 8, 9}, {1, 2, 9, 10}, {1, 2, 
        10, 3}}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2}]
     }];
mesh = MeshOrderAlteration[mesh, 2];
mesh["MeshOrder"]
```

> 2

Also with my original mesh:

```
mesh = Import["http://1drv.ms/1ynockn", "ExpressionML"];
MeshRegion@mesh
mesh = MeshOrderAlteration[
   mesh /. elem : {__HexahedronElement} :> {HexahedronElement @@ 
       Join @@@ Transpose[elem /. HexahedronElement -> List]}, 2];
mesh["MeshOrder"]
```

> 2

Comment: In your simpler example, if you combine the several `HexahedronElement` into a single one, `MeshOrderAlteration` works:  `mesh2 = MeshOrderAlteration[mesh /. elem : {__HexahedronElement} :> {HexahedronElement @@ Join @@@ Transpose[elem /. HexahedronElement -> List]}, 2]`.  I don't know how `MeshOrderAlteration` works and its limitations, but let me know if it works on your actual mesh.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Wow, Yes, It does, Thanks. How do you discovered/suspected this?

Comment: I suppose it's a somewhat standard problem solving strategy:  Find an example (or two) that works and compare it to the example that doesn't.  An `ElementMesh` is not a very complicated data structure and there are not many things that can be different. The obvious and principal difference was that your example had a list of several `HexahedronElement`. Since `MeshOrderAlteration` is an internal function, it may not have the robustness that one expects of user-level functions.

Comment: I filed this as a possible future improvement. You can also use `MeshOrderAlteration[
 ToElementMesh["Coordinates" -> mesh["Coordinates"], 
  "MeshElements" -> MeshElementMerge[mesh["MeshElements"]]], 2]` to merge the mesh elements.

Comment: @user21 Thanks. I'm experiencing another issue with `MeshOrderAlteration` and point markers in 3D. How `MeshOrderAlteration` assign point markers to 2nd order nodes? Sometimes - I noticed - a second nodes "inherits" its marker from adjacent first order nodes markers, if they are equal. But this doesn't happens always...

Comment: @unlikely, that's non-trivial, I'd need to see an example to say if there is an issue.

Comment: @user21 Would you like I post a different question?

Comment: @unlikely, that's probably best, but I need some time until I can look at it.

Comment: @user21 It is legal to act "inside" and `ElementMesh` (as in the answer of @MichealE2), without extracting elements and rebuilding mesh with `ToElementMesh` (as in your comment), for example if I only want to move sligtly the coordinates or if I only wnat to change markers?

Comment: Moving coordinates will change the mesh quality, so I would not recommend that. You may get away with merging elements. As long as that does not change the topology. If you want to create your own mesh generator you could call `ElementMesh` directly, `ElementMesh[coords,ele,...]` or `ElementMesh[coords,Automatic,bcele,...]` . If you are sure that the boundaries do not intersect you could switch the intersection check off. `Options[ElementMesh]` but I would not fiddle with the mesh quality option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OP's simpler mesh has the form

```
mesh
(*
  ElementMesh[{{-0.707107, 0.707107}, {-1., -0.11547}, {-0.707107,  0.707107}},
   {HexahedronElement["<" 64 ">"], HexahedronElement["<" 64 ">"], 
    HexahedronElement["<" 64 ">"], HexahedronElement["<" 64 ">"], 
    HexahedronElement["<" 64 ">"], HexahedronElement["<" 64 ">"], 
    HexahedronElement["<" 64 ">"], HexahedronElement["<" 64 ">"], 
    HexahedronElement["<" 64 ">"], HexahedronElement["<" 64 ">"]}]
*)
```

If you combine the several `HexahedronElement` into a single one, `MeshOrderAlteration` works:

```
mesh2 = MeshOrderAlteration[
  mesh /. elem : {__HexahedronElement} :>
   {HexahedronElement @@ Join @@@ Transpose[elem /. HexahedronElement -> List]},
  2];
mesh["MeshOrder"]
(*  2  *)
```

I don't know how `MeshOrderAlteration` works nor its limitations, but it is possible that, since it is an undocumented internal function, it handles element meshes only in the form(s) in which they arise internally.